# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una clase JPanel dentro de un panel en una ventana principal?

Tags: java, jpanel

Tengo un programa con el mismo código, sin embargo, uno de ellos no muestra la clase dentro del panel.

```
Volumen V=new Volumen();

public Ventana() {
    initComponents();
    panel.add(V);
    V.setVisible(true);

}
```

Volumen es la clase JPanel que estoy intentando visualizar dentro de la variable panel.

Comment: P.D: Se ejecuta con normalidad, pero no muestra nada.

Comment: Tu clase está incompleta por lo que tu códio de ejemplo no compila. Siempre trata de poner un [mcve]